# Raspberry - same address in every location

Tags: pi-2, connection, dns

I have an RPI2 what I want to use as a "developer platform" with git and mysql server. I using dyndns for remote access, but! when I home I can access it from 192.168.1.125 and when I'm remote I can from "myrpi.dynalias.net". How to access Rpi from home with this address, too?

Comment: Have you done a port forwarding in your firewall to get "myrpi.dynalias.net" to work?

Comment: Yes, the "myrpi..." working from ouside of thr the network, but insode it not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `192.168.1.125  myrpi.dynalias.net` to your hostfile.

In windows it is normaly located at:

```
c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

Linux:

```
/etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

Your router/firewall probably is probably blocking the NAT loopback, some firewalls block it by default as security measure and you must manually create a rule to allow it.
How to enable NAT loopback depends on the make and model of your firewall, you can probably, searching for "[router/firewall model] nat loopback" would be the place to start.